# Smartqueue Per User for Drupal 7 - alternative

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Can someone tell me a module that can do the same functionality than "Smartqueue Per User" for Drupal 7
http://drupal.org/project/smartqueue_users

I need to associate a kind of node to a user that clicks on it. A good example can be a job candidate that responds/applies to a job role on a job add.
I've found Queue module bue it does not register each individual user.

Can someone tell me an alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: i used a module called [FLAG](http://drupal.org/project/flag)